# Running RSpec Files From ruby code

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm trying to run RSpec tests straight from ruby code. More specifically, I'm running some mysql scripts, loading the rails test environment and then I want to run my rspec tests (which is what I'm having trouble with)... I'm trying to do this with a rake task. Here is my code so far:

```
require "spec/autorun"
require"spec"
require "spec/rake/spectask"
RAILS_ENV = 'test'

namespace :run_all_tests do 
  desc "Run all of your tests" 

  puts "Reseting test database..." 
  system "mysql --user=root --password=dev < C:\\Brian\\Work\\Personal\\BrianSite\\database\\BrianSite_test_CreateScript.sql" 
  puts "Filling database tables with test data..." 
  system "mysql --user=root --password=dev < C:\\Brian\\Work\\Personal\\BrianSite\\database\\Fill_Test_Tables.sql" 

  puts "Starting rails test environment..." 
  task :run => :environment do 
    puts "RAILS_ENV is #{RAILS_ENV}"
    # Run rspec test files here...
    require "spec/models/blog_spec.rb" 
  end 
end
```

I thought the require "spec/models/blog_spec.rb" would do it, but the tests aren't running. Anyone know where I'm going wrong?

UPDATE: I've added the require "spec/autorun" command at the top of the file and now I am running into this error when I do a rake run_all_tests:run :

C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-1.3.0/lib/spec/runner/options.rb:283:in `fi
les_to_load': File or directory not found: run_all_tests:run (RuntimeError)
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-1.3.0/lib/spec/runner/options.
rb:275:in`each'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-1.3.0/lib/spec/runner/options.
rb:275:in `files_to_load'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-1.3.0/lib/spec/runner/options.
rb:133:in`run_examples'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-1.3.0/lib/spec/runner.rb:61:in
 `run'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-1.3.0/lib/spec/runner.rb:45:in`
autorun'
        from C:/Ruby/bin/rake:19

It's hitting this error when it gets to the require "spec/models/blog_spec.rb" line. This file does exist because when I try and change the require statement, I just get a file not found error. It seems like rspec is trying to now run the tests, but is running into problems... any thoughts?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `require "spec/autorun` to the top of your file.

You don't need to do it that way though, because there are built in Rake tasks (that's what the `spec/rake/spectask` is including) to do what you're doing: http://rspec.info/documentation/tools/rake.html

Comment: I tried adding the require "spec/autorun" but now I am getting an error. I've updated my question with the error I am getting. Thanks for the help.